# How to fix an error Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to integrate google play billing library with my android application and when I try to add this dependency  `(compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0')`  in the app module's `build.gradle` file. I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Possible causes:
The project 'work' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.4.1 and sync project

The project 'work' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks already.

Comment: you have put in wrong section it needs to be in module app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **Build.gradle(Module:App)** :

[image]

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I have been digging their manuals for hours on this.

Answer (score 1):

Below dependency should not be added in top level gradle

```
compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
```

Add it in app module gradle.

And compile keyword is deprecated now you can use below new version

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
```